# Minecraft server has prompt issues with tmux on cygwin

Tags: cygwin, minecraft, bukkit, tmux

I am attempting to run a Bukkit server on tmux in Cygwin (using babun). Starting the server in tmux looks fine at first, but once it's finished starting there is no prompt on screen (>). I believe that this has something to do with Bukkit's use of JAnsi, as it says that it's not able to instantiate a WindowsAnsiOutputStream:

```
Loading libraries, please wait...
2016-01-17 19:42:51,385 WARN Unable to instantiate org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream
...
```

I would like to know a solution to this, because without the prompt, I am unable to type and send a command to the server while it is outputting text.

My start.zsh:

```
java -server -Xms4G -Xmx4G -jar craftbukkit-latest.jar nogui nojline
```

(I have no ~/.tmux.conf)

My tmux command for starting the server:

```
tmux new-session -n minecraft ./start.zsh
```

Comment: Are you sure its not accepting any input? try typing a command and pressing enter

Comment: @Ferrybig It does accept input, but when I'm trying to type something and more text is outputted by the server, the input is 'split' across the lines. [example](http://i.imgur.com/QU8p0pA.gifv)

Comment: I assume the Java you're running it with isn't compiled for cygwin. Non-cygwin/msys programs don't tend to like running inside a terminal emulator. Have you tried running it with winpty?

Comment: Can you try the stuff at http://sourceforge.net/p/jline/bugs/40/ (stty command and `-Djline.terminal=UnixTerminal`)?

Comment: You put `nojline` in the argument for the server.  That makes it directly take input rather than using a fancy formatter (that handles lines and has a `>`).  Does removing the `nojline` parameter fix it, or does removing it break it further?

Comment: @Pokechu22 No, removing nojline nor keeping it there seems to make a difference

Comment: Does anybody know of a solution for this problem?